# Trying to identify a electronic parts company logo SC

Tags: identification

[image: Text]

Have this DC power connector,   and looking for the manufacturer using this logo.

SC text  in a parallelogram

Comment: Do you really care about the manufacturer? Maybe you better look for the connector type in case you need a replacement/mating connector?

Comment: There are a great number of manufacturers of this kind of part (probably 100s in China alone), and probably you won't find them in distribution anyway. On the other hand, you can likely find a compatible part in distribution.

Comment: a manufacturer might glean a part number